# Use Powershell variable in JSON

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-core

I am trying to pass a parameter through a function in powershell but it is not working

Code

```
function test($test1, $test2)
{
 $details = @"
{ "updateDetails": [
    {
        "customer": "John",
        "rank": $test1
    },
    {
        "school": "western",
        "address": $test2
    }
    ]
}
"@
return $details
}
test 0 florida
```

Current issue

```
{ "updateDetails": [
    {
        "customer": "John",
        "rank": 
    },
    {
        "school": "western",
        "address": florida
    }
    ]
}
```

I tried running test but the value 0 is not filled in the details json, florida is filled in correctly. How can I replace the two values. Also how can florida be in string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 fills in for me, but florida doesn't have quotes, which is invalid JSON.
To make life a little easier, instead building a here-string, consider building an object and converting it to JSON with the built-in cmdlet [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7).

In this example I'll show you how to do it using a hashtable

```
function test($test1, $test2)
{
 $details = @{ 
 "updateDetails"= 
 @(
    @{
        "customer" = "John"
        "rank" = $test1
    },
    @{
        "school" = "western"
        "address" = $test2
    }
    )
}

return $details | ConvertTo-Json
}

test 0 florida
```

output

```
{
    "updateDetails":  [
                          {
                              "customer":  "John",
                              "rank":  0
                          },
                          {
                              "school":  "western",
                              "address":  "florida"
                          }
                      ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine. I ran your example and it worked as expected. Maybe you missed updating the function. Close the shell and then try again.

To include `"florida"` as string you could simply add quotes around the variable `"$test2"`, or even safer: Use [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7) to output a properly quoted and escaped JSON string:

```bsh
function test {
    param ([int]$rank, [string]$address)
    return @"
    { "updateDetails": [
        {
            "customer": "John",
            "rank": $rank
        },
        {
            "school": "western",
            "address": $(ConvertTo-Json $address)
        }
        ]
    }
"@
}
test 0 florida
```